How to see changes in every Ubuntu update?
I want to know what has changed in Ubuntu 22.04.1 vs 22.04.2, but I cannot find ANYTHING. There is only some "download link" for 22.04.5 .
What is the main website that has details about every release? (When they are released, how to see the changes, and how to update to them. Is it a normal apt-upgrade)?
I only found this link that is not my question.

Release notes for 22.10 = 22.04.1 = https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-notes/27976?_gl=11wsf2z9_gcl_auOTA5Njc2OTkyLjE3MTQ4OTU0MjU.  23.04 = 22.04.2  = https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-notes/31910?_gl=1ulpoae*_gcl_au*MTg3MTA0MTQyLjE3MTU1MTY0Mjg.

If you scan the announcements of a later point release you'll find the following  (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/)

As usual, this point release includes many updates and updated
installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need
to be downloaded after installation. These include security updates
and corrections for other high-severity bugs, with a focus on
maintaining stability and compatibility with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

ie. the point release has all the upgraded packages included, that get 're-spun' into a new ISO available for download, should you need to re-install.
For some systems, there can be a change in kernel stack, and a new installer provided, eg.
Lubuntu 22.04 LTS & 22.04.1 media used and installed with the GA kernel stack (5.15 kernel), however 22.04.2 and later media would use and install a HWE kernel stack; but that's the standard for Ubuntu flavor Desktop, as it was for Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS & earlier too.  Ubuntu Desktop (20.04 & later) & Ubuntu Server do not however have these kernel stack changes.
In essence, the point release is a reflection of security fixes and other package updates being applied.

The ISO available easiest, naturally contains all security fixes applied (ie. 22.04.4 currently), however if you look (https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/) you can find the older ISOs too, only you'll end up with the same result after install and security fixes/upgrades are fully applied.
The only real benefit (I see) of the older ISOs is for Quality Assurance and other testing, as post-install and upgrades it'll be identical to later media; but if used live (without install) you can contrast bugs using the current (updated or installed system) as against what was provided with an older stack (ie. without updates).
An older 22.04.2 media is useful to view a snapshot of what occurred at some historical point in time (release of the ISO) before later security fixes were applied. Thus why they're not easily found; they're not useful to most people (just requiring more security fixes to be applied post-install; when it kernel stack changes; those are easily changed post-install anyway)

If you want to view the BUGS fixed in the later point release, they're available too, eg. for Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (the same release I used earlier) you can view

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-point-release-changes/29835/5
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-point-release-changes/29835/6
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-point-release-changes/29835/7

ie. install any Ubuntu 22.04 LTS media & apply all security fixes and you'd get those updates, but those posts show what was included on 22.04.4 over the prior 22.04 media.   Multiple only links due to the size allowed in discourse posts (there are costs with increasing post size; using multiple posts a cost-effective workaround)

I'm quoting from the Ubuntu Fridge release announcement as its a link I can easily find (for obvious reasons), but the TEXT itself is standard & used on most of the announcements, being taken (copy/pasted) from official text (the ML link is at the bottom which is used for Ubuntu News posts on the Fridge).

I've used Lubuntu as example again as easiest for me, but it applied to any Ubuntu flavor. The difference between kernel stacks is just a package change.. thus (almost always) easiest to use the latest ISO and change it manually post-install rather than finding & using an older ISO anyway then applying all security fixes post-install..  The testing & live is something where I find the older ISOs useful... helpful in tracking down changes/bugs... but I doubt many will find benefit with that anyway.

Are there the point releases during 5 years of standard support or during 10 years of Ubuntu Pro?

Only 5 point releases are scheduled for Ubuntu LTS releases, though historically there have been extras released during the standard support cycle (eg. 16.04.7 that are spun usually because of revoked SHIMs or security flaws requiring new media.. There have been none thus far (publicly available) for any release in ESM/Extended support, or Pro (or legacy) but that could change; OR they've just not been available publicly.   FYI:  Ubuntu flavors have the option of involvement too past .5; its not mandatory.

If you're after a list of changes... I give example of what changed using 22.04.4 or the latest 22.04 ISO respin... but updated packages are listed in many sources.. eg. Ubuntu News publish them weekly in the Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter with the latest issue read at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-weekly-newsletter-issue-838/44648 in "Updates and Security for Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, 23.10, and 24.04"  (or subscribe to a ML & have them emailed to you!)

my last comment refers to ML subscription; which could be obtained by following links provided within UWN.. but if not you can just use https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/jammy-changes  to get emails of all changes for the jammy or 22.04 system (this ML will include all packages, not just what you have installed)
